# Are pitches that are put into play counted as strikes or balls?

Tags: baseball, pitching

I have often seen a pitcher's pitch count displayed on the screen with it broken up into **strikes**, **balls** and **total** pitches. So something like

> Strikes :  25
>   Balls   :  15
>   Total   :  40

My question is, are pitches that are put into play counted as strikes or balls (ie fouls balls, pop-ups, base hits, etc)? I am assuming they are counted towards the total... so they would have to be quantified as a strike or ball.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All balls in play are counted as strikes.

This is a basic principle of pitching. [If the batter swings at the pitch, it's a strike.](http://www.baseballprospectus.com/article.php?articleid=1905)

This gives us 2 categories of pitches that are counted as strikes:

- balls in the strike zone that are not swung at
- balls that are swung at

There is only one category of pitches categorized as balls:

- balls that are not swung on and are not in the strike zone.